# Trying to make other cells shrink and one cell expand when hovering over that cell on a table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so when I *hover* one of these cells, it gets **bigger**, and all the other cells get **smaller** *(but not disappear)*, but I also don't want the cell to expand outside the table or make the borders of the table bigger.

How to solve this?

**CSS code:**

```
.Grid_Options {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Titillium Web;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border: 0;
}

.Grid_Options td {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: black;
}

.Grid_Options td:hover {
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #686868;
    color: #DDD;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
      <table class="Grid_Options" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
                  <td>Placeholder</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46433002/edit) to explain how your included example differs from what you're looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also don't want the cell to expand outside the table or make the borders of the table bigger.

We can do this by removing your `padding` size increase on `:hover`, and replacing it with a `transform: scale`. This doesn't affect the flow of any other items in the CSS.

Note that we also need to add `overflow: hidden` to the table now so the scaled cells don't spill over the edge.

```css
.Grid_Options {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* add this */
}

.Grid_Options td {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: black;
}

.Grid_Options td:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1); /* add this */
  background-color: #686868;
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table class="Grid_Options" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked but I have one more question if I wanted to shrink the other cells too, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: @PinguMcDude You could keep your original code with `padding` and define a `width` and `height` on the table (`.Grid_Options`). That would prevent the cells from making the table grow.

Comment: This worked for all sides except the bottom, the bottom of the table does grow even though I set a specific width and height, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Jon Uleis gave perfect answer. But if you need also to shrink other cells, here is modified css for this.

```css
.Grid_Options {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* add this */
}

.Grid_Options td {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: black;
}
.Grid_Options:hover td {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.Grid_Options:hover td:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1); /* add this */
  background-color: #686868;
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table class="Grid_Options" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You also may want to try scaleX transform function instead of scale to keep row height unchanged.

Comment: This worked to a certain extent, but it only shrinks the one directly next to the cell I'm hovering on, the one on the bottom and the ones on the other sides are not affected.

Comment: I updated a snippet, check again plz. I didn't got that you need all the cells in the table, not in the current row only.